# Update the values of a month's dictionary based on the current month - PYTHON3

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary as shown below.

```
months_dict = {"m1":"JAN", "m2":"FEB", "m3":"MAR", "m4":"APR", "m5":"MAY", "m6":"JUN",
               "m7":"JUL", "m8":"AUG", "m9":"SEP", "m10":"OCT", "m11":"NOV", "m12":"DEC"}
```

Which I would like to update with last 12 months as shown below.

Expected output:

```
current_month_dict = {"m1":"MAR", "m2":"APR", "m3":"MAY", "m4":"JUN", "m5":"JUL", "m6":"AUG",
                      "m7":"SEP", "m8":"OCT", "m9":"NOV", "m10":"DEC","m11":"JAN","m12":"FEB"}
```

My try:

```
from datetime import datetime
current_month_text_3 = datetime.now().strftime('%h').upper()
```

I am stuck after that. I tried a lot by looping over the dictionary and creating a static month list and all. Could not figure out correct logic.

Comment: what do you mean by update current month the current month in your case is feb right why would you put it in m12 and not m1 then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is what you are looking for m1 here is the next month as i started the loop from i=1 you can do a i=0 to get m1 as feb

```
from datetime import datetime

arr_months = ['JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC']


def transform_month_list(month_list):
    current_month_text_3 = datetime.now().strftime('%h').upper()
    idx = arr_months.index(current_month_text_3)
    for i in range(1, 13):
        month_list["m" + str(i)] = arr_months[(idx + i) % 12]


default_months_dict = {"m1": "JAN", "m2": "FEB", "m3": "MAR", "m4": "APR", "m5": "MAY", "m6": "JUN",
                   "m7": "JUL", "m8": "AUG", "m9": "SEP", "m10": "OCT", "m11": "NOV", "m12": "DEC"}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        transform_month_list(default_months_dict)
        print(default_months_dict)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use such syntax

```
{ modify_func(key) : val for key, val in months_dict.items()}
```

In you case

```
 >>> { f"m{(int(key[1:]) + 9) % 12 + 1}" : val for key, val in months_dict.items()}                                      
    {'m11': 'JAN', 'm12': 'FEB', 'm1': 'MAR', 'm2': 'APR', 'm3': 'MAY', 'm4': 'JUN', 'm5': 'JUL', 'm6': 'AUG', 'm7': 'SEP', 'm8': 'OCT', 'm9': 'NOV', 'm10': 'DEC'}
```